# (Shiny R) Subset data from uploaded file + selection by widgets

Tags: r, shiny

I have problem with subset function.

I need to implement subset function in my application but application is not willing much to cooperate. When I try to display subsetted table it only shows colummn names and rest of table is empty.

Having in mind fact, my application has many functions implemented already (histogram, braplot, boxplot, count etc...) I put fragments of code needed only for subset function.

```
h4("Wybierz plik z danymi na których program StatMaciej będzie pracował"),  
fileInput("file", label = h5("Wybierz Plik")),


  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Pierwszy wiersz to etykiety', value = FALSE),
  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Wzkaż znak oddzielający kolumny', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Średnik"=';',"Tabulator"='\t', "Spacja"=''), selected = ','),
  radioButtons(inputId = 'dec', label = 'Co jest separatorem dziesiętnym', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Kropka"='.'), selected = ',')
```

This fragment is part of UI where file is uploaded, and things like separator are selected using widgets.

```
conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.histogrup == '2'",
        selectInput("combobox8", label = h5("Wybierz kolumne ze zmienną grupującą"),  choices = NULL),
selectInput("combobox9", label = h5("wybierz grupe"),  choices = NULL)

)
```

This fragment is for widgets which I select variables for subset. combobox8 is for selecting column and combobox9 is for selecting unique variable in selected column.

```
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, dec = input$dec )

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))


    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox1", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox2", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox3", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox4", choices = colnames(dataSet))
        updateSelectInput(session, "combobox5", choices = colnames(dataSet))
            updateSelectInput(session, "combobox6", choices = colnames(dataSet))
            updateSelectInput(session, "combobox7", choices = colnames(dataSet))
            updateSelectInput(session, "combobox8", choices = colnames(dataSet))




    dataSet
  })
  observe ({
            updateSelectInput(session, "combobox9", choices = unique(as.character(data()[[input$combobox8]]))) 
  })
```

There is fragment of server.r responsible for uploading file and updating widgets, also there is observer part to update "combobox9"

```
output$tabelatest <- renderTable({



    subset(data(), input$combobox8==input$combobox9)

      })
```

this is fragment for subset. It creates subsetted table.

```
tableOutput("tabelatest"),
```

And of course last part of code in ui, responsible for displaing table.

I tried to do some trick in subset part (like "paste" command) but it didn't work. So I'm here looking for help.

Comment: if you want to filter multiple column you should try `DT` with `filter` it will be easy and you can remove 2 combobox from your app https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: yes. But problem is i want use got filtered table for example to create histogram.

Comment: you want something like this https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-info/

Comment: hmm. its not also that is what i need. I want to create table with filtered data what i will use to create a histogram. I want just to know why my subset function doesen't want to work with my inputs.

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in your code the part where you subset the data on base of `combobox`. Additionaly Your code is very complicated/or shall i say not well copied (--> where are `selectInput`'s for all the `combobox`??). There is no sample data, and its it definately not reproducible example...